# How to upload open and read large(20 mb) csv file?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am working on csv file upload and i need to upload large csv files and then need to insert into database with field mapping.I am doing this using Jquery it is not showing any error just show the url into red color into firbug. I am not getting what is the problem?This is my script.

```
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/create_input.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                var value= $("#valS").val();
                var host=$('#host').val(); 
                //alert(host);
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: host+"views/excel_file_import.php",
                    data: {value: value},
                    success: function(html){   
                    $('#Exceloutput').html(html);  
                    }
                });  
            });
        }); 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#updatefields").click(function(){ 
    var arrayOfValues = $(".bookDetails select").map(function (i, el) { return      $(el).val(); }).get();
    var fileName= $("#excelfile").val(); 
    var csvState= $("#state_csv").val(); 
    var host=$('#host').val(); 
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: host+"views/update_fields.php",  
        data:{str:arrayOfValues, fileName:fileName, csvState:csvState}, 
        success: function(msg){  
            $('#fieldUpdate').html(msg);  
            }  
         });

    return false; 

    });
    }); 
    </script> 
    <?php
    $host=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $url=substr($host,0,-9);
    ?>
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="host">
   <h1 class="page-title">Upload Csv File</h1>
   <div class="container_12 clearfix leading">
   <div class="grid_12" id="edit-form">


    <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>views/excel_file_import.php" method="post"     enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm" class="form has-validation">

      <div class="clearfix">
               <label for="form-upload" class="form-label">Upload File<em>*</em></label>
               <div class="form-input">
                   <input type="file" size="50" class="text" id="excelfile" name="excelfile" required="required"/>
                   <input type="hidden" size="50" class="text" id="valS" name="valS"  value="1" required="required"/>
               </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-action clearfix">
             <button class="button class-button" type="submit"   id="SubmitButton">Upload</button>
             <button class="button class-button" type="submit" id="updatefields" name="updatefields">UpdateExcel</button>
     </div>


    </form>
    <div id='fieldUpdate'>
    </div>
    <div id='Exceloutput'>
    </div>

    </div>
     </div>
```

and this is excel_file_import.php code.

```
<?php
include("../common/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $database= "test2";
    $filename = 'test-'.$_FILES['excelfile']['name'];
    $value= $_POST['value'];
    $copy= move_uploaded_file($_FILES["excelfile"]["tmp_name"],"../files/".$filename);
    if($copy)
    { echo "Upload Success";?>

<?php
}

}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see an upload widget here.  You can't upload files through vanilla ajax.

Comment: have you included the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the file upload limit in `php.ini` file:

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M //needs to be in {x}M format
```

see more info here:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes
2. http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-file-upload-limit-using-php-ini
3. http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Increase_php.ini_Upload_Limit
4. http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Comment: yes i have increase the upload_max_filesize but there is no change.

Comment: have you included the jquery?

Comment: yes i have included this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

Comment: hi i have checked for error into error log file and it is showing this error. mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 138520 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072) . Please help me out if anyone can...

Comment: checkout this if helps: http://www.opensource-excellence.com/blog/item/430-cant-upload-files-due-to-fcgi-maxrequestlen-restriction-in-plesk.html

Comment: Thanks for reply jai but we are using isp config hosing can you please help me how we can change there?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this using jQuery. it is not showing any error. It is just showing the url into red color into firbug

Are both the files residing on same domain? html and php both? Firebug is showing that red color url because cross domain ajax request is not allowed normally

Comment: Yes both files are on same domain. when i upload csv file with small amount of data it upload file successfully but when i try to upload 8mb file it shows the url in red color.

Comment: Then look for a solution according to @Jai's answer. Also check your timeout value, because obviously uploading a large will fill take longer and your jquery might be timing out

Answer (score 0):

For uploading large files on server check these setting in php.ini file and if you don't have access of php.ini than you can change it htaccess file.Increase value of these file uploads according to your requirements.

max_input_time 1000
max_execution_time 1000
post_max_size 1000M
max_file_uploads 50
upload_max_filesize 1000M